# How can I get two programs to have the same sequence of random numbers?

Tags: delphi, random, numbers

Is it possible for 2 applications (a server and a client) to generate the same sequence of random numbers? What I need is this:

On server:

```
i1:=randomrange(10,50); //i1 will be 15
i2:=randomrange(10,50); //i2 will be 40
i3:=randomrange(10,50); //i3 will be 20
```

On client:

```
i1:=randomrange(10,50); //i1 will be 15
i2:=randomrange(10,50); //i2 will be 40
i3:=randomrange(10,50); //i3 will be 20
```

The sequence needs to be dependent of a value that the server calculates and sends it to the client

Comment: If you use the same random number generator on both server and client side, and initialize the generators with the same seed, you should get the same "random" number sequences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Random number generators are typically, in fact, pseudo random. Given the same initial state, the pseudo random number generator (PRNG) will generate the same sequence of numbers.

Typically thia state is provided by means of a seed. If you are using the PRNG provided by the RTL then you set the seed by assigning a value to [`RandSeed`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.RandSeed). Use the same seed in each program and you will generate the same values.

If you are using a different PRNG then consult its documentation to find out how to seed it.

Comment: David is right, but he assumes a non-cryptographic PRNG.  If you want the same random, then avoid cryptographic PRNGs, they are designed not to give the same random even with the same seeds -- they take other system variables as well as any supplied seed to initialize the RNG.

Comment: @rossum As David said, PRNG generates same sequence if it has same initial state. If generated sequence is not 100% defined by initial state, then it is not PRND. That is true for any PRND, including cryptographic ones.

Comment: Cryptographic PRNGs do have an initial state.  It is just that the initial state is not completely defined by the user.  As well as the used-supplied seed they use various internal system-level sources of entropy which are, at least in theory, difficult for an attacker to determine.  The initial state exists, but is not fully user-determined.  Hence no two instances can reliably be set to the same initial state.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement a pseudo random sequence yourself you may start from linear congruential generator. Actually it is very easy

[image: the formula]

and there are only 3 restrictions on the ***a***, ***c*** and ***m*** values

1. ***m*** and ***c*** are relatively prime,
2. ***a-1*** is divisible by all prime factors of ***m***
3. ***a-1*** is divisible by 4 if ***m*** is divisible by 4

See [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) wiki for details.